# Check if UWP-Application is in Foreground/Focused

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

I want to check if the current application is in the foreground/focused.
The application is a windows-10 UWP application.

What i already got is, to check if the current application is minimized. For that i use the  `VisibilityChanged` event of  `Window.Current`.

But i don´t find a solution, to detect if the application is in foreground or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure but it seems that [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Activated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.activated.aspx) event should suit your needs.

Comment: This works in my quick tests. I tried this earlier, but i didn´t found the "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated" State. I must be blind. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You app cannot know it is in background because it does not run when in background. You can only react to the app getting suspending. For more info, check out the App lifecycle documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt243287.aspx

Comment: Okay, maybe i have to clarify what i mean with foreground/background:
I want to detect if the application window is in the foreground. Means for me, the application is running, but another windows is in front of my application. I hope this makes it more clear

Comment: What if my app uses ExtendedExecution to continue work while minimized? How do I know if the app is currently minimized or not?