# Set inactive color for customized titlebar

Tags: c#, uwp, titlebar

I followed the uwp [titlebar sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/TitleBar), it works fine except one thing, the color of the titlebar is always the same, but it should be different when the window is not in the foreground, I tried to use `LayoutMetricsChanged` and `IsVisibleChanged` to listen to the defocus event but it is not working, so how can I set the different color of the new bar and make it like a real one?

Comment: To check if the Application has the focus maybe look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857990/check-if-uwp-application-is-in-foreground-focused

Comment: `InactiveBackgroundColor` specifies the title bar color when the window is not foreground.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, but the customized titlebar is a UIelement, not a Applicationviewtitlebar, so no such setting is available.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question. You have a custom-drawn title bar (not just custom-color title bar). You can ask for UISettings.UIElementColor(InactiveCaption) to find out what the inactive caption color is. You can change the color when your window activation state changes. `IsVisibleChanged` tells you when to show/hide your custom title bar. (E.g., the user makes the app fullscreen, so the title bar hides. Then the user bumps the mouse into the top of the screen, and the title bar temporarily reshows.)

Comment: @RaymondChen UISettings.UIElementColor is part of what I was looking for, thanks. So there is no way to let the UIElement act like a titlebar and set the color itself? I thought `Window.SetTitleBar` would do it. Besides this, it looks there are totally 12 colors(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewtitlebar.aspx) I need to take care of in order to make the titlebar real like the system one some of them are not in `UIElementColor` Enum.

Comment: Accord. to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.settitlebar.aspx, `SetTitleBar` "Makes a XAML element interact with the system as if it’s the title bar", it appears it does not do his job well.

Comment: @fluter Note the description" Makes a XAML element **interact with the system** as if it's the title bar." The system handles the interaction, e.g., clicking and dragging to move the window. But the system has no idea how you want your title bar to alter its appearance when inactive. Do you want to change opacity? Do you want to change the colors? Do you want to hide some controls? That is on you. When you make a custom title bar, you are taking full responsibility for the appearance.

Comment: @RaymondChen So handling of appearance is not part of interactions, so I misunderstood it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this article : [Eternal Coding - Take the control of your titlebar](https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=1952).

You will have to handle the event `Window.Current.Activated`. For example, here is the code extracted from the same article:

```
private void Current_Activated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.WindowActivationState != CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated)
    {
        BackButtonGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MainTitleBar.Opacity = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        BackButtonGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        MainTitleBar.Opacity = 0.5;
    }
}
```

This snippet will update the opacity of its custom title bar when the window gains or losts focus.